# Check if data was updated in database

Tags: laravel

When i update data in a database is there a way to check if the value stayed the same or if a new value was entered.

```
  $update_email = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->update($request->all());
```

The above will return true even if the data is the same or not.

Comment: You could retrieve the user and check against the values from the request.

Answer (score 2):

Start by using fill instead of update:

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->fill($request->all());
```

Then you will have to check each attribute to see if changed:

```
$emailChanged = $user->email !== $user->getOriginal('email')
```

Then save before you finish up:

```
$user->save();
```

You may be able to use a for loop to iterate through the attributes rather than hard code email like I did.  Either way the gist of the answer is, this isn't built in to eloquent and you will have to manage it yourself more or less.

Edit after seeing the other answer, there is actually a method `getDirty()` which will return the attributes that have changed:  https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_getDirty

Answer (score 2):

You can check it before:

```
$user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);

$user->fill(request()->all();

if($user->isDirty()) {
    // update happened 
}

$user->save();
```

Comment: Didn't know about `isDirty()`, nice answer!  Will still have to check manually to figure out what changed though, right?

Comment: @Jeff getDirty()

Comment: If you want to check after the model has been saved you can use `wasChanged()`. You can also check a specific attribute by calling `wasChanged($attribute)` or `isDirty($attribute)`. Note that a 'changed' attribute was updated since the model was retrieved but has been saved, and a 'dirty' attribute has been updated but not saved.